# iron-list [first,last]VisibleIndex bindings don't work?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

I am using a polymer iron-list and trying to dynamically respond to scrolling to create an infinite list of information.

I'm finding that I can't get data binding to work on the firstVisibleIndex and lastVisibleIndex properties, nor am I able to get events from those properties when they change.

I'm binding the properties to variables like this:

```
  <iron-list id="list" items="[[items]]" as="item" first-visible-index="{{fvi}}" last-visible-index="{{lvi}}">
    <template>
      <div>
        <center>[[item.value]]</center>
      </div>
    </template>
  </iron-list>
  <p>binding: [[fvi]], [[lvi]]</p>
```

I am able to scroll around, an in my plnkr example I also have a timer that reads the properties using javascript.  The actively read values are correct.  The bound values are always 0.

I tried using an event to trigger the active read (on-first-visible-index-changed) but it doesn't fire.

Any ideas what it takes to get iron-list to cough up these properties?

Complete plnkr here:   https://plnkr.co/edit/nY7amL?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`firstVisibleIndex`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/blob/6412911/iron-list.html#L681) and [`lastVisibleIndex`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/blob/6412911/iron-list.html#L706) are actually read-only non-declared properties, which don't emit change-events (which prevents two-way data binding and change-listeners).

Any properties that are listed in the element catalog without a **notifies** annotation on the righthand side are *not* observable. For instance, in `iron-list`'s docs page, you'll notice [`selectedAs`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list#property-selectedAs) does not show `notifies` on the right, but [`selectedItem`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list#property-selectedItem) does, indicating that you could bind the latter to an output property.

Comment: Well, that's a somewhat subtle documentation note. :-P  Any suggestions on how to get an event when scrolling does happen?

Comment: Try [`<iron-scroll-threshold>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-scroll-threshold)

Comment: It's puzzling to me that iron-list can't emit a scroll event.  Is this an oversight, or am I expecting it to do something it's not meant to do?

Comment: I did manage to get iron-list to emit a scroll event.  Either it's not well-documented, or I have a blind spot, but I figured out I can use this attribute on iron-list:  on-scroll="_onScroll", and implement reading the first and last visibleIndex values from _onScroll.  Accepting this answer because tony correctly pointed out that these are not bindable properties.